# What are Filson hats?

Tags: clothing, wool

I saw the following -

[image: Filson hats]

*Filson Hats*: Navy USA-Made 60198 NA Merino Wool Cuff Water-Resistant Cap

The  cap/hat is described as [Filson hat](http://workingperson.com/filson-hat-navy-60198-na-merino-wool-cuff-cap.html). Is this a brand-name or the type of hat ? If it's not the hat/cap type, what are such caps/hats called ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Filson](http://www.filson.com/men/hats-and-caps.html) (C.C. Filson Co.) is a company that sells many types of outdoor hats.

The particular style of hat you pictured in your question goes by several different names.

> - Here in Canada it is known as a [toque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toque) or tuque. Even though other terms are in existence up here, the only phrase I really seem to hear up here is toque. Except for Canada the term primarily used for this hat is a *knit cap*.
> - The [Knit cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knit_cap) originally of wool is designed to provide warmth in cold weather. Typically, the knit cap is of simple, tapering constructions, though many variants exist.
> - The Filson Company uses the term [Wool Cuff Cap](http://www.filson.com/men/hats-and-caps.html) for this particular knit cap.

Comment: Yes there are seemingly [unbounded names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knit_cap#Other_names) for that kind of hat. Two names that I've heard them called in the US is beanie (very common) and watch cap (more nautical name).

Comment: In addition, "Filson Hat" would more typically refer to the Tin (Oil) cloth hats which were Filson's big early product.

Comment: I should add that I've lived in Canada all my life (Calgary), and I don't think I've ever heard anyone under like 50 say "knit cap". Overwhelmingly, the term I've used and heard used is "toque".

Answer (score 3):

Yes FILSON is a company.  That is commonly called a stocking cap.

That is kind of expensive for cap.  But it is a nice cap.

Answer (score 2):

I would comment, but I need reputation for that.

That is a 'Touque'.

[the proper spelling](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/edmonton/thousands-vote-on-correct-spelling-of-canadian-knit-cap-1.2457737). A significant amount of untrustworthy votes on CBC'S webpoll agree on the spelling of touque.

Really, just spell it however you like.

In the United States it's also commonly called a "beanie".